# React: Inserting a line break in localised text

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting localised text from a JSON file and displaying it to the page, my problem is that the `\n` and `<br>` notations are being ignored.

I've made a code sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-rgb-c1o2z) to show how the text doesn't get put on more than one line.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const App: React.FC = props => {

  const Translations: {
    [key: string]: {
      fname: string;
    };
  } = {
    en: {
      fname: "I want to insert a break in this line of text so it shows on two lines \n doesnt work and <br> does either",
    },
    cn: {
      fname: "我想在这一行文本中插入一个中断，以便在两行中显示\ n不起作用，而<br>可以",
    }
  };

  const txt = Translations["en"];


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>{txt.fname}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Have you tried to set `style="white-space: pre-line"` on your `<p>`?

Comment: I just tried it and it ignores the `\n` and just prints `<br>` as if its text and doesn't interpret either as a line break.

Comment: sorry, got the code wrong for React.  I've now created an answer that works in your sandbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to respect `\n`, you can add a style of `white-space: pre-line` or `white-space: pre-wrap`.

In React, it would look like this:

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      <p style={{ whiteSpace: "pre-line" }}>{txt.fname}</p>
    </div>
  );
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-almeida-5tioj) is a forked sandbox.

Comment: In the sandbox link, you sent me the text remains on a single line

Comment: there was a small typo in the original sandbox.  I've now updated the link.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, however make sure to sanitize your input with smth like [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify):

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: txt.fname
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

As mentioned in the comment, another way is to replace `<br>` with `\n` and add `whiteSpace: "pre-line"` css rule:

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p style={{ whiteSpace: "pre-line" }}>
        {txt.fname.replace("<br>", "\n")}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
```

[Working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-darkness-b1yf0).

Comment: Its a last resort but id get dragged through the mud in a code review

Comment: Yeah, but since in your case you only need to deal with whitespaces, you could replace `<br>` with `\n` and add `style={{ whiteSpace: "pre-line" }}`. Just tried this in the sandbox and it deals with `\n` properly.

Comment: I wish it showed two line for me, I just get `Type '{ whitepace: string; }' is not assignable to type 'CSSProperties'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'whitepace' does not exist in type 'CSSProperties'. Did you mean to write 'whiteSpace'?`

Comment: wth, it works for me, not sure how can a sandbox show different results, maybe you can try the code in your local dev env/editor?

Answer (score 1):

use css property `white-space: pre-line`
`<p style={{ whiteSpace: "pre-line" }}>{txt.fname}</p>`

Comment: I can assure you that the <br/> and `\n` is just printed as if its text

Answer (score 0):

You could always use JSX instead - it would look like this

```
  en: {
      fname: <p>"I want to insert a break in this line of text so it shows on two lines \n doesnt work and <br> does either"</p>
    }
```

```
 return (
    <div className="App">
      {txt.fname}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: I now get `Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'string'.` what should the type be for jsx ?